# React TS - How to map through FontAwesome icons and display them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, font-awesome

I'm trying to create a reusable component that allows me to pass in the `href`, `target`, `rel` attributes along with the type of FontAwesome Icon I would like to use. I'd like to be able to pass as many icons as I would like into this list and it would map through them, using the Social component as a template.

I would like the map to happen within the `Social.tsx` file, then I can simply just add the component anywhere in my project and then pass the props to it.

Something like this:

```
<Social
  icons={[
    { icon: "facebook", href: "", target: "", rel: "" },
    { icon: "twitter", href: "", target: "", rel: "" },
    { icon: "discord", href: "", target: "", rel: "" }
  ]}
/>
```

I currently have my component:

**Social.tsx**

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import * as React from "react";

interface ISocial {
  href?: string
  target?: string
  rel?: string
}

const Social: React.FC<ISocial> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href={props.href} target={props.target} rel={props.rel}>
        {/* I don't want to hardcode the icon, but dynamically pass it as a prop */}
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", "discord"]} />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Social;
```

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Social from "./components/Social";

export default function App() {
  // I'd like to be able to pass in a list of different icons
  // followed by the href, target, rel, etc for each item.
  // The Social component would be able to map through them
  // and display them.
  return <Social />;
```

How can I adapt this to do what I described above?

> **Here's a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-field-85uxf)**

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a list of strings with icon names and use `map` if required to have list.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Social
      icons={[
        { icon: "facebook", href: "", target: "", rel: "" },
        { icon: "twitter", href: "", target: "", rel: "" },
        { icon: "discord", href: "", target: "", rel: "" }
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

Changes to Social Component. Just add new prop like `name`

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import * as React from "react";
import { IconName } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";

interface ISocial {
  href?: string;
  target?: string;
  rel?: string;
  icon: IconName;
}

interface ISocialList {
  icons: Array<ISocial>;
}

const Social: React.FC<ISocialList> = props => {
  const { icons } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {icons.map(item => {
        return (
          <a href={item.href} target={item.target} rel={item.rel}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", item.icon]} />
          </a>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Social;
```

Code changes to your sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-bush-br14l

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the quick response! I'd prefer to have the map done within the `Social` component if possible?

Comment: @Jordan, Updated the answer and sandbox. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I’m looking for but I’d like to be able to pass the array directly to the tag itself, see my question for an example.

Comment: @Jordan, Updated the answer and sandbox.  Slight changes to `icons` prop values to have valid array.

Comment: We're making progress! :) Almost there, but it's giving a type error on line 21 `icon={}` for Social.tsx?

Comment: @Jordan, Oh right. Fixed that TS error and updated both places.  You just need to maintain `const names` with supported icons.

Comment: Is this the cleanest fix possible for the TS error? I was hoping it would be more simple

Comment: Ah, you are right. I just updated/simplified.  Using `IconName ` type directly is the key.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the problem is with structuring the props that you want to pass.

For instance, we will pass an array of type `IconProp` then you can easily map over it.

Now you can make your own interface and pass props of this type

```
interface myType {
  href?: string;
  target?: string;
  rel?: string;
  icon: IconProp;
}
const dummyProp: myType[] = [
  { icon: ["fab", "discord"] },
  { icon: ["fab", "discord"] },
  { icon: ["fab", "discord"] },
  { icon: ["fab", "discord"] }
];

const Social: React.FC<ISocial> = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {dummyProp.map(p => (
        <a href={p.href} target={p.target} rel={p.rel}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={p.icon} />
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the repsonse. I'd like to pass the array from the `<Social />`, it's not very dynamic if it's hardcoded in the component itself.

Comment: Yes, I know this was just an example, any way you should get a list of the icons you want to pass somehow, so structure something like this interface, in any component you need and pass it down as props.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused, could you give an example of what you're describing please?

Comment: checkout this https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-chebyshev-8eqim
Well, I don't know why facebook and twitter icons are not shown, but it does not matter

Answer (score 0):

```js
//App.tsx

import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Social from "./components/Social";

export default function App() {
  // I'd like to be able to pass in a list of different icons
  // followed by the href, target, rel, etc for each one.
  // The Social component would be able to map through them
  // and display them.

  const iconList = [
    {
      name: "twitter",
      href: "https://www.google.com",
      target: "_blank"
    },
    {
      name: "discord",
      href: "https://www.google.com",
      target: "_blank"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {iconList.map(ico => {
        return <Social icon={ico.name} href={ico.href} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}


//Social.tsx

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import * as React from "react";

interface ISocial {
  href?: string;
  target?: string;
  rel?: string;
  icon: String;
}

const Social: React.FC<ISocial> = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href={props.href} target={props.target} rel={props.rel}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", props.icon]} />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Social;
```

Comment: Hi there. I'd like the map to happen within the `<Social />` itself, and the ideall just pass the array to the `<Social icons=[{icon="", href="", target="", rel=""},  icon="", href="", target="", rel=""] />` tag.

Comment: I updated the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-turing-r9fzz

Comment: This is better, the map is now inside the component but can I pass the iconList array to the <Social /> tag like I mentioned above?